# -> operator that breaks evaluation on encountering a nil/false return

Tags: clojure

I want to thread an input through a series of functions, just what the -> operator does. However if any of the functions returns nil / false then I would like to break the evaluation and return back an error message. How do I do that, is there some operator / macro that provides this functionality ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this one: [`-?>`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_contrib/clojure.contrib.core/-_q%3E) 
From documentation:

```
(-?> "foo" .toUpperCase (.substring 1)) returns "OO"
(-?> nil .toUpperCase (.substring 1)) returns nil
```

If you will use `->` macro for second example, you will definitely get `NullPointerException`.

Comment: For completeness, let's mention that it is in the `clojure.core.incubator` namespace, in the main Clojure jar.

Comment: @AlexBaranosky See first comment from OP.

Comment: Sure, but it doesn't matter what he wanted.  It matters what he asked.  It will confuse people reading this question months/years from now.

Comment: As of Clojure 1.5 this is provided by core, and is named `some->`

Answer (score 3):

There is also the `maybe-m` monad in `clojure.algo.monads`. Being part of the monads framework it is more heavyweight than the `-?>` macro, so it makes sense to use `maybe-m` if you are using monads anyway or if your computation graph is more complicated than a simple chain of functions.

Unlike the threading macros, the`domonad` composition can handle multiple argument functions that take arguments from multiple previous steps of computation:

```
(domonad maybe-m
    [a 1
     b nil
     c (* a b)]
    c)
```

In this example,`(* a b)` won't get evaluated, since `b` is nil. The whole expression will return nil instead of throwin an exception from trying to multiply by nil.

Comment: The maybe monad is a bit dangerous because it does punning of Nothing and nil. This violates the monad laws (http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/ALGOM-7) which can lead to problems if nil is a valid value in the computation.